# Json from string using regular expression

Tags: javascript, json, regex, string

I have a string like:

```
const stringVar = ":20:9077f1722efa3632 :12:700 :77E:  :27A:2/2 :21A:9077f1722efa3632 :27:1/2 :40A:IRREVOCABLE"
```

I want to create JSON from above `stringVar`:

```
{
  ":21:" : "9077f1722efa3632",
  ":12:" :  "700",
  ":27A:":  "2/2",
  ":21A:":  "9077f1722efa3632",
  ":27:" :  "1/2",
  ":40A:":  "IRREVOCABLE"
}
```

So, I was thinking I could split with regular expression `(":(any Of char/digit):")`
I would make the first part the key and the second part its value.

Answer (score 2):

The regular expression `/(:\w+:)(\S+)/` matches the whole `key:value` pair. You can add the `g` modifier, and then use it in a loop to get all the matches and put them into the object.

```js
const stringVar = ":20:9077f1722efa3632 :12:700 :77E:  :27A:2/2 :21A:9077f1722efa3632 :27:1/2 :40A:IRREVOCABLE"

var regexp = /(:\w+:)(\S+)/g;
var obj = {};
var match;
while (match = regexp.exec(stringVar)) {
  obj[match[1]] = match[2];
}
console.log(obj);
```

If you want to create an array of `{key: ":20:", value: "9077f1722efa3632"}`, you can modify the code to:

```js
const stringVar = ":20:9077f1722efa3632 :12:700 :77E:  :27A:2/2 :21A:9077f1722efa3632 :27:1/2 :40A:IRREVOCABLE"

var regexp = /(:\w+:)(\S+)/g;
var array = [];
var match;
while (match = regexp.exec(stringVar)) {
  array.push({key: match[1], value: match[2]});
}
console.log(array);
```

If the values can contain space, change the regexp to:

```
/(:\w+:)([^:]+)\s/g
```

This will match anything not containing `:` as the value, but not include the last space.

Comment: Hey Barmar

Thanks for quick respone

I have used your solution but in results there are few tags missing

can you try this string
":20:9077f1722efa3632 :12:700 :77E:  :27A:2/2 :21A:9077f1722efa3632 :27:1/2 :40A:IRREVOCABLE :20:NONREF :40E:EUCP LATEST VERSION :31D:171231 sddfsdf :51A:sdf :50:asdfasdf asdf :59:asdf asdfasdf :32B:CAD23,12 :41A:ADVISING BANK BY DEF PAYMENT :42P:100% Payment At 30 Days  :44C:171231 :45A:dfsdf +CFR :46A:+Logistics +Commercial Invoice  :47A:9077f172-18ac4c89-8131-fce442efa363 :49:CONFIRM :57A:02DFDFN"

and get all tags also :77E: with empty value

Comment: i see that some fields are same and json replace previous key if key is same
so may be we can return array with [ {"name":"","value":""},{"name":"","value":""}]

Comment: Does that have spaces in the values? From your example I thought that space was the delimiter between each `:key:value` pair.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same result without using `regex`.

```js
const stringVar = ":20:9077f1722efa3632 :12:700 :77E:xxx :27A:2/2 :21A:9077f1722efa3632 :27:1/2 :40A:IRREVOCABLE";

const result = stringVar
  .split(' ')
  .reduce((ret, current) => {
    const pos = current.indexOf(':', 1);
    ret[current.substring(0, pos + 1)] = current.substring(pos + 1);
    return ret;
  }, {});

console.log(result);
```